# How do you post photos on user's timeline from Windows phone mobile app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-7.1, photos

I am trying to post photos from my Windows 7.1 mobile app into the user's timeline.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look on [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) which now supports Windows Phone. I think to see a photo in timeline it is enough to upload it. If you were referring to information in the past, I believe it is not possible with current Api.

Photo Upload working sample code

http://igrali.com/2012/06/07/share-photos-on-facebook-from-windows-phone-app/ 
http://facebooksdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/facebook-album.html

Interesting thread with additional discussion and examples

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/258497